# Show message when WCF service is down

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have searched about, how to know if WCF service is down OR not and I came to know that the only way to know this is to call WCF service method. We can create a method that just return true. 
In my case I want to show a message when service is down to the client and for other exceptions of WCF service, I want to show the exceptions as it is. What should be the best way to this ?

Comment: Use a try/catch block around your wcf service call. And in the catch block display the exception thrown by the webservice call ? Aren't you searching something more complicated than it has to be ?

Comment: Actually you don't even need to return `true`. Make it a `void`.  If any part of it fails the service will fault naturally

Answer (score 1):

If the service is yours then go ahead and use that method that returns true.

However, you should just go ahead and consume the service, as it's not necessarily true that it will remain up the entire time that you consume it. Handle your interim timeouts and errors gracefully for all of your operations and show your messages accordingly.

One client-side thing you can do is send a WebRequest and see if it returns a `HttpStatusCode.OK` but it can't promise you that the service won't fail or is running.

During your consuming the service you can expect `FaultException`, proxy and channel state errors, invalid configuration (bindings, etc) and `CommunicationException` objects.

You can read more on this on **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715.aspx)**.

From there:

> > Communication errors occur when a network is unavailable, a client uses an incorrect address, or the service host is not listening for incoming messages. Errors of this type are returned to the client as CommunicationException or CommunicationException-derived classes. Application errors occur during the execution of a service operation. Errors of this kind are sent to the client as FaultException or FaultException.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved only "client side", because server can reply with "true" only if WCF service is running and well configured.

All the other case should be managed from client.

In a simple way you can call that simple service if it reply it seems all OK, otherwise you'll get a faultexception or an exception that you need to catch.

Pay attention at async / await, you need to catch exception in the closer place to the web call otherwise you'll get an uncaught application exception that will crash app domain.

Comment: OP's question, as i understood it, was more like : how to display the exception as is.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 There are specific exceptions for "Destination unreachable" in WCF so based on the type of exception detail, the client should have a pretty good idea of what went on.  I know my stuff does

Comment: @MickyD Sorry if you misunderstood me, for me it was obvious from the OP's question that he wanted the exceptions to be thrown and displayed on the client side.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 No misunderstanding. I myself catch 5 specific MS exceptions client side all of which one can use to determine the _type_ of fault :)